# Copy SQLite database from assets folder

Tags: android

I wanna copy SQLite database from assets folder. This my DatabaseAdapter.java class

```
package com.example.dictionary;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.dictionary/databases/";
    static String DB_NAME = "dict.db";
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context mContext;

    public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void createDB(){
        boolean dbExist = checkDB();
        if (dbExist) {

        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDB();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying DB");

            }

        }
    }

    private void copyDB() throws IOException {
        InputStream dbInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFile = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream dbOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = dbInput.read(buffer))>0) {
            dbOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        dbOutput.flush();
        dbOutput.close();
        dbInput.close();

    }

    private boolean checkDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase check = null;
        try {
            String dbPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
            check = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        if (check!=null) {
            check.close();
        }

        return check != null ? true : false;
    }

    public void openDB(){
        String dbPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    public synchronized void close(){
        if(db != null)
            db.close();
        super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

When i run app it isn't error. but when i check databases folder i saw file "dict.db" but only 12.00K and has only android_metadata table. Please help me. thanks.

Comment: Please use `SQLiteAssetHelper` for this: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: Be aware that from Android Pie the solutions below may no longer work. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476782/android-p-sqlite-no-such-table-error-after-copying-database-from-assets#answer-50630708 for the answer

Answer (score 8):

put all this method in ur helper class.

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * This method will create database in application package /databases
 * directory when first time application launched
 **/
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!mDataBaseExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            mIOException.printStackTrace();
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        } finally {
            this.close();
        }
    }
}

/** This method checks whether database is exists or not **/
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    try {
        final String mPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        final File file = new File(mPath);
        if (file.exists())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * This method will copy database from /assets directory to application
 * package /databases directory
 **/
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    try {

        InputStream mInputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = mInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            mOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        mOutputStream.flush();
        mOutputStream.close();
        mInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/** This method open database for operations **/
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String mPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    return myDataBase.isOpen();
}

/** This method close database connection and released occupied memory **/
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    SQLiteDatabase.releaseMemory();
    super.close();
}
```

Comment: is it possible to copy/create only table from assets?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar Yes It is possible.

Comment: can you plz provide any url ?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar you can use above code for asset database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code..

```
void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("mydb.sqlite");
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void CopyDatabase() throws IOException {
    openOrCreateDatabase("you_db_file.db", 0, null);
    InputStream mInput = getAssets().open("databases/forall.db");
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/you_db_file.db");
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        int mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer);
        if (mLength > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        } else {
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.close();
            mInput.close();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way of doing it, use getDatabasePath()

```
    String dbFilePath = getDatabasePath("main.db").getAbsolutePath();
    File dbFile = new File(dbFilePath);
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("main.db");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int read;
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IllegalStateException("failed to copy db file");
    }
```