# How to pregenerate sqlite database in gradle build script

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, gradle

I've Android application that has some hardcoded data in *sqlite* database.
How to **pregenerate** the **database** file **in** the **gradle script** e.g. from text file containing *sql commands* (or maybe two, the second one will contain creation of android specific table `android_metadata`)?

I expect that file will be stored in *assets* folder and copied to proper (internal database) folder during application initialization. E.g. like here:

[How to use my own sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387421/how-to-use-my-own-sqlite-database)

or

[What is a Full Android Database Helper class for an existing SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548533/what-is-a-full-android-database-helper-class-for-an-existing-sqlite-database)

I know that I can run sql command during the db initialization, but I don't want to bother every device cpu to do the same thing.

Comment: You could install the `sqlite3` binary on your development machine and write a Gradle task to use it to run your SQL statements and create your database. Or, you could find a plain Java library that interfaces with SQLite and use it as part of a custom Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, find it by myself:)

in `build.gradle` of your app:

```gradle
...
configurations {
    driver
}

dependencies {
    ...
    driver 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.20.1'
    ...
}

URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
configurations.driver.each {File file -> loader.addURL(file.toURI().toURL())}

task createDB << {
    ext.loadScript = { sql, file ->
        println("Applying " + file)
        String[] sqlcmds = file.text.split(";")
        sqlcmds.collect{it.trim()}.findAll{!it.isEmpty() && !it.startsWith("--")}.each{
            try {
                sql.execute(it)
            } catch(java.sql.SQLException e) {
                System.err << "Invalid SQL statement: " + it
                e.printStackTrace(System.err)
                throw.e
            }
        }
    }

    def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance('jdbc:sqlite:path/to/asset/folder/dbfile','','','org.sqlite.JDBC')
    new File("path/to/sql/init/files").eachFileMatch(~/.*\.sql/) {loadScript(sql, it)}
    sql.close()
}
preBuild.dependsOn createDB
```

don't forget to add android specific creation sql script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US');
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "android_metadata" (ROWID, "locale") VALUES ((SELECT ROWID FROM "android_metadata" WHERE "locale" = 'en_US'), 'en_US');
```

Also you must handle recreation (e.g. either delete the db file before it's created or put safe sql statements like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` or `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO` intu init scripts)

How to load it in application is answered e.g. here:
[Copy SQLite database from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354154/copy-sqlite-database-from-assets-folder)